# Angular 6 mergeMap for nested api calls

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, observable

With the traditional observable/subscribe pattern I am trying to get a list of clients, with each of those clients get a list of their accounts with client.id

Here's what that looks like:

```
this.httpService.getClients().subscribe(clients => {
    clients.forEach(client => {
        this.httpService.getClientAccount(client.id).subscribe(accounts => {
            console.log(accounts);
        });
    });
});
```

Now I'm trying to do this with mergeMap. I do not think I'm doing it correctly as when I pass in client.id to the second call it is showing as undefined.

```
this.httpService.getClients().pipe(
    mergeMap(client => this.httpService.getClientAccount(client.id))
).subscribe(result => console.log(result))
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? I tried using tap() to console log the client inside mergeMap but nothing showed up. I'm not sure how to reference the response from the first getClients() call.

Comment: The object emitted by the source Observable is a list of clients still.

Comment: Yes, how do I get each individually? I just use the forEach in the first way but how do I do it with mergeMap?

Comment: Might consider [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) instead for the scenario.

Comment: @ChrisW. I would still need to know how to use it in my example above...

Comment: @TimKlein didn't tag u above

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use `forkJoin` as mentioned above by Chris W.:

```
const outerObservable = of([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);

outerObservable.pipe(
    mergeMap(inputs => forkJoin(inputs.map(input => rxjs.of(input)))),
);

outerObservable.subscribe(console.log);
```

See example 3 from [this page](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) and example 1 for info on how to use a dictionary approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is correct way to do it but this returns each account for each client:

```
this.clientService.getAllClients().pipe(
    mergeMap(clients => clients)).pipe(
    mergeMap((client:any) => this.accountService.getClientAccts(client.id)))
    .subscribe(res=>console.log(res));
```

The first mergeMap flattens the clients array to each individual client I believe then can use client.id to make the second call.